# How to replace some string in generic list in linq

Tags: linq, generics, asp.net-mvc-4, generic-list

i have generic list in my application which has image path in every record.that image path would be different for different sites. so path would be changes accordingly. i want to replace path in list only and then will sent to my view. Image contains path :"department/DEPTIMAGE.JPG". now i want a list where image should be "PetDeptImages/DEPTIMAGE.JPG" How will i change my list ? Please suggest. My List is :

```
 var list = nav.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId.Equals(Id)).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you mean replacing that path for _all_ images in the list, or for that exact single image?

Comment: specifying here don't wanna change whole path ! just a folder name i.e all image path would contains PetDeptImages inplace of department , the image name would be remain same.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string path = "PetDeptImages/";
var list = nav.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId.Equals(Id) && x.Path.Contains(path)).ToList();
```

Assuming your nav lists has a property of `Path`.

Comment: specifying here don't wanna change whole path ! just a folder name i.e all image path would contains PetDeptImages inplace of department , the image name would be remain same.

Comment: i want to replace that string in my existing list in place of department/, u didn't get the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work;

```
var list = nav.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryId.Equals(Id))
                           .Select(x => Regex.Replace(x, "^department/",
                                                         "PetDeptImages/"))
                           .ToList();
```